# Segmentation Faults on Database Gems For Ruby 1.9.2 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, rubygems, mysql2

I'm trying to get a rails app up and running on Windows Server 2008, and have hit a road block...  I've installed the mysql2 gem and whenever I try to require it in irb to test the install, I get a nasty segmentation fault.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>gem install mysql2
Successfully installed mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32...
Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Client not known
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32...
Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Client not known

C:\Users\Administrator>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'mysql2'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]

-- control frame ----------
c:0035 p:-11375406 s:0122 b:0122 l:000121 d:000121 TOP
c:0034 p:---- s:0120 b:0120 l:000119 d:000119 CFUNC  :require
c:0033 p:0013 s:0116 b:0116 l:000115 d:000115 METHOD :29
c:0032 p:0032 s:0111 b:0111 l:000110 d:000110 TOP    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2
c:0031 p:---- s:0109 b:0109 l:000108 d:000108 FINISH
c:0030 p:---- s:0107 b:0107 l:000106 d:000106 CFUNC  :require
c:0029 p:0013 s:0103 b:0103 l:000102 d:000102 METHOD :29
c:0028 p:0072 s:0098 b:0098 l:000097 d:000097 TOP    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:7
c:0027 p:---- s:0096 b:0096 l:000095 d:000095 FINISH
c:0026 p:---- s:0094 b:0094 l:000093 d:000093 CFUNC  :require
c:0025 p:0073 s:0090 b:0090 l:000086 d:000089 BLOCK  :33
c:0024 p:0014 s:0087 b:0087 l:000086 d:000086 METHOD :29
c:0023 p:0011 s:0082 b:0082 l:001f94 d:000081 EVAL   (irb):1
c:0022 p:---- s:0080 b:0080 l:000079 d:000079 FINISH
c:0021 p:---- s:0078 b:0078 l:000077 d:000077 CFUNC  :eval
c:0020 p:0028 s:0071 b:0071 l:000070 d:000070 METHOD C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80
c:0019 p:0033 s:0064 b:0063 l:000062 d:000062 METHOD C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/context.rb:254
c:0018 p:0031 s:0058 b:0058 l:0003e4 d:000057 BLOCK  C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:159
c:0017 p:0042 s:0050 b:0050 l:000049 d:000049 METHOD C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273
c:0016 p:0011 s:0045 b:0045 l:0003e4 d:000044 BLOCK  C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:156
c:0015 p:0144 s:0041 b:0041 l:000024 d:000040 BLOCK  C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:243
c:0014 p:---- s:0038 b:0038 l:000037 d:000037 FINISH
c:0013 p:---- s:0036 b:0036 l:000035 d:000035 CFUNC  :loop
c:0012 p:0009 s:0033 b:0033 l:000024 d:000032 BLOCK  C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229
c:0011 p:---- s:0031 b:0031 l:000030 d:000030 FINISH
c:0010 p:---- s:0029 b:0029 l:000028 d:000028 CFUNC  :catch
c:0009 p:0023 s:0025 b:0025 l:000024 d:000024 METHOD C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228
c:0008 p:0046 s:0022 b:0022 l:0003e4 d:0003e4 METHOD C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155
c:0007 p:0011 s:0019 b:0019 l:000ca4 d:000018 BLOCK  C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:70
c:0006 p:---- s:0017 b:0017 l:000016 d:000016 FINISH
c:0005 p:---- s:0015 b:0015 l:000014 d:000014 CFUNC  :catch
c:0004 p:0183 s:0011 b:0011 l:000ca4 d:000ca4 METHOD C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69
c:0003 p:0039 s:0006 b:0006 l:0017b4 d:000334 EVAL   C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:0017b4 d:0017b4 TOP
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `start'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `catch'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:70:in `block in start'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `each_top_level_statement'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `catch'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `loop'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:243:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:156:in `block in eval_input'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273:in `signal_status'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:159:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/context.rb:254:in `evaluate'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80:in `evaluate'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80:in `eval'
(irb):1:in `irb_binding'
:29:in `require'
:33:in `rescue in require'
:33:in `require'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:7:in`'
:29:in `require'
:29:in `require'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `'
:29:in `require'
:29:in `require'

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

I've tried copying the libmysql.dll over to my Ruby bin folder, and that didn't help.
I've even tried using the mysql gem and get the same kind of error but this time on the mysql_api.so file.

Then I thought I might just try sqlite3 and I still got the error.

If it makes any difference here are my versions:

C:\Users\Administrator>mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.83, for Win32 (ia32)

C:\Users\Administrator>rails -v
Rails 3.0.3

C:\Users\Administrator>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]

I hope someone can help me.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ruby installer on windows:

- Use libmysql from mysql 5.1 with ruby 1.9.2
- Use libmysql fro mysql 5.0 with ruby 1.8.7

In both cases you can use the My SQL Server 5.1.  It will work with the older client library when you are working in ruby 1.8.7.